# How to display the album art for a particular song?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-alarms, android-cursor, android-music-player

I'm creating a music player and now I am stuck on displaying the album art for particular songs.

Please help me.

Comment: Please share your code. It is impossible to help you this way

Comment: Okay I will upload it after some time because my lapi is not with me.

Comment: You want to pool album cover from mp3 file, or from internet? Or you asking how to properly display image?

Comment: I want to get album art from my local storage, @Ekalips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use this code to get the album art for particular song.

```
ContentResolver res = getContentResolver();
            Uri smusicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor music =res.query(smusicUri,null,null, null, null);

            music.moveToFirst();
            int x=music.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
                String albumArt = music.getString(x);
            Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(albumArt);
                ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IValbumArt);
```

Comment: I did this but it displays albums but not matching with song exactly @HirenJungi